# Android Softkeyboard: can't use startActivityForResult

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

I am about to develop a soft keyboard for Android with a key to scan Barcode.
For this I've extended the **InputMethodService** override the **onKey** and on pressing of specified key I've launched a new activity i.e. the barcode scanning activity (using **ZBarScannerView** for scanning), now on successfull scanning I somehow want the result back to the IMS. Since the scanner activity is launched from a service I can't use **startActivityForResult**

Can anyone suggest me an alternative for that?

Answer (score 0):

Your activity could store it in a SharedPreference, and then your IME could check that same SharedPreference to read from.

Comment: See the problem is I don't have an event in IME to get the data back.